# Magento URL Rewrite Issue

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url, dns, url-rewriting

thanks in advance for looking at my post.

I am getting quite confused about my Magento URLS

At present my URL appears like: http://exache.com/varifocal-vandal-proof-1080p-dome-camera

However I want it to appear like http://exache.com/cameras/dome-cameras/varifocal-vandal-proof-1080p-dome-camera

So instead of domain/product I would like it to appear domain/parent-category/sub-category/proudct..

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this product assigned to only one sub-category?

Comment: Yes only one sub-category.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Try following:

1. Login to Magento Admin
2. Go to Catalog Configuraiton. (System -> Configuraiton -> Catalog)
3. There, you'll see Search Engine Optimizations section (on right column)
4. Expand that and Select Yes to "Use Categories Path for Product URLs"
5. Save config

Refresh cache and try browsing front-end.